# JavaScript - My checkbox (which is checked by default) doesn't run it's script on page load

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I apologize if this is something really simple, but I'm relatively new to JavaScript. I've scoured the web to find a solution but haven't found anything!

So I'm building a sort of "settings" UI for a Google Chrome extension popup and I'm using checkboxes to enable/disable options. I want one of the checkboxes to be checked by default, so I have the `checked` attribute defined in its HTML like so;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" style="margin-left: 20px;" checked>
                                                        <!-- ^ Right here ^ -->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I implemented a script here so that if the checkbox is checked, a certain script will be programmatically injected. If it isn't checked, it will inject a different script. Code:

```
document.getElementById("option1").addEventListener("click", toggleOption1);

function toggleOption1() {

  var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");

  // if option1 is checked, run first script
  if (option1.checked === true) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
          file: 'optionEnabled.js'
        });
  // otherwise, run script 2
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
          file: 'optionDisabled.js'
        });
    }
}
```

Now, this has worked great for me so far, it does exactly what it intends to do except for *one* thing:
I want the code to be run automatically because, duh, the checkbox is checked by default. The code only recognizes when the box is unchecked or checked by the user.

**Note:** I am aware that this line of code

```
document.getElementById("option1").addEventListener("click", toggleOption1);
```

means that the function is run on click and I should just use `onclick="toggleOption1()"` instead, but because I am making a chrome extension, inline scripts are not allowed.

**Note 2:** I would appreciate it if the solution could avoid JQuery or other external libraries, but if nothing else is available, I guess it's okay!

**Note 3:** I would provide a JSFiddle, but I don't believe there's a way to implement the chrome extension environment.

Anyone out there know a way to fix this? I've been confuzzled for several days and I'd really like to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to run the `toggleOption1` function by default on page load then you should try `document.ready`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know by default that checkbox is checked then you can simply execute your code
chrome.tabs.executeScript
From the background script and not from the popup script.

Background script is loaded once the extension is loaded.
Background script has one instance for all tabs.

**update:**
It will do it only one time when the extension is loaded. So no problem for the user to play with the checkbox after that from thr popup

Comment: Using this method, would the user still be able to turn off the extension? Or does it just continue forever?

Answer (score 1):

call

```
   toggleOption1();
```

after

```
    document.getElementById("option1").addEventListener("click", toggleOption1);
```

**EDIT**

You should use something like DOMContentsLoaded event to make sure the Data Object Model is loaded

**JavaScript**

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        
   
      
      document.getElementById("option1").addEventListener("click", toggleOption1);
       toggleOption1();
  });
function toggleOption1() {

  var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");

  // if option1 is checked, run first script
  if (option1.checked === true) {
    console.log("checked");
    // chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    //       file: 'optionEnabled.js'
    //     });
  // otherwise, run script 2
  } else {
    console.log("not checked");
    // chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    //       file: 'optionDisabled.js'
    //     });
    }
}
```